# Lambda function not executing http.get

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a function that when tested locally worked fine, but when running via AWS Lambda doesn't seem to execute the HTTP get. 
The code is as follows:

```
function makeAPIRequest(path, responseControl, callback) {

    var responseString = '';
    console.log("Executing makeAPIRequest to " + apiSettings.host + " and path " + path);
    var options = {
        host: apiSettings.host,
        path: path,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-Auth-Token': apiSettings.token
        }
    };
    http.get(options, function (res) {
        console.log('Status Code: ' + res.statusCode);
        if (res.statusCode != 200) {
            callback(new Error("Non 200 Response"));
        }
        res.on('data', function (data) {
            responseString += data;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            console.log('http end function hit...');
            callback(null, responseString);
        });
    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.log("Communications error: " + e.message);
        callback(new Error(e.message));
    });
}
```

I initially wrote it using the request npm package but that failed, so I dropped back to vanilla http.get, but neither seems to execute. In the log output from Lambda I can see the output of the following:

```
console.log("Executing makeAPIRequest to " + apiSettings.host + " and path " + path);
```

with the correct host and path being passed in, but

```
console.log('Status Code: ' + res.statusCode);
```

never outputs to the screen. There are no errors logged and the API endpoint that I'm hitting reports the number of API requests, but this isn't changing, so I dont think the request is even being made.

Has anyone got Lambda to make http calls and if so, any ideas on what I'm not doing here?

Thanks

**Edit: verified that 'no vpc' is set in the advanced settings section of lambda**

Comment: Does your lambda end with a timeout? What is its timeout setting?

Comment: I just checked that a slightly simplified version of your code works for me. What other callbacks do you have that may block the handler of `http.get()` from starting?

Comment: Thanks Leon, you led me down the correct path.
Turns out the spaghetti code that is JavaScript had a problem with how my callbacks were being handled so the Lambda function wasn't "waiting" for the response.

Answer (score 5):

I see some variation of this question on here every few days. In almost every case it is because you placed the Lambda function in your VPC. Lambda functions don't get public IP addresses assigned to them inside a VPC, so they don't have access to anything outside the VPC. This results in network calls to resources outside the VPC hanging like what you describe.

The solution is to either move the Lambda function outside of the VPC, or add a NAT gateway to your VPC.

Comment: Just logged in and its set to 'No VPC' , which, as I understand it, should allow internet access by default. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. So where is the API you are trying to hit? Is it something that is exposed to the Internet?

Comment: Yes, you can see a sample response here: http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/?season=2016

Comment: That should work then. Next I would try wrapping the call in a try/catch to see if some exception is being thrown.

Comment: Added a try/catch and there's no difference in the output. Still no response and the catch function doesn't fire...

Comment: I've also tried changing from passing in the options object to just passing in the URL as the first parameter to http.get in case it was a headers problem, but that yeilded the same result